# remove a certain column, but still include it in sql statement

Tags: asp-classic

As you can see from my sql statement i am pulling a column called title. I need this column pulled as it provides information i need to add to a particular column, however i do not want the column (header text) title to be shown how can i remove it, while keeping  it in my sql.

I know it has to do with for each x in rs.fields in that loop but i cant get it to not include title

```
x = ""
    for each x in rs.Fields
        response.write("<th align='left' bgcolor='#D3FFA1'>" & x.name & "</th>")
    next%>
    </tr>

    <%do until rs.EOF%>

    %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   for each x in rs.Fields
        if x.name <> "title" then
            response.write("<th align='left' bgcolor='#D3FFA1'>" & x.name & "</th>")
        endif
    next%>
```